Interpreting the Y-axis of a visreg visualizaion of a binominal logistic regression model
This is a long post, apologies for the length. In sum, I just want to know what the Y-axis represents in the below plots.
Here's the background:
I have a binomial logistic regression model in which the response variable and explanatory variables are binary factors.
The explanatory variables and their possible values are the following:
Genre: "PEN" or "TN"
Speech_VP: "CH" or "N"
Here is the summary of my model as a glm object:
Call:
glm(formula = EV ~ Genre + Speech_VP, family = binomial, data = df_ev2)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-2.0115  -0.4628  -0.1381   0.5326   3.0519  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value             Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -4.6475     0.5115  -9.086 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
GenreTN       4.0611     0.4379   9.274 < 0.0000000000000002 ***
Speech_VPN    2.4675     0.3762   6.559       0.000000000054 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 434.02  on 313  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 227.37  on 311  degrees of freedom
AIC: 233.37

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5

I understand the values of the coefficients and such, but I'm trying to picture what this would look like. Linear regression is easy to visualize, and even logistic regression with a continuous response variable is also easy to visualize.
However, what would a logistic regression model look with purely factorial variables? I was reading a paper that uses the visreg package for R to visualize binomial and purely factorial logistic regression model. I tried the same and got the following result:
visreg(ev2.glm, "Speech_VP", by = "Genre")


Generally, I think I understand what the plot shows. The points are the observed values, the blue line represents the fitted values, and the grey area around the blue line the residuals. The fitted value line and residual areas are cut up into disconnected "slices" because everything here is factorial.
I also believe I understand the overall relationship between the plot and the model. For example, the probability that the B value of the response variable will be selected over the reference level is higher when Genre = TN, so the slices of the model in the TN area are higher on the Y-axis than the slices of the model in the PEN area.
By the same token, for the Speech_VP variable, the probability of choosing value B over the reference level of the response variable is higher when Speech_VP = N, so the two slices of the model corresponding to the N values on the X axis are higher on the Y axis than the slices corresponding to the CH values.
Now what I don't understand, is what the numbers on the Y-axis represent. My first thought was that these might be scale of the log odds, but none of the log odds values of the predictor coefficients seem to line up with the values on the Y-axis. Or if they did, what would they line up with? The regression line representing the fitted values?
To try and simplify things, I used visreg to plot just one predictor. Here's the plot of the Speech_VP variable:
visreg(ev2.glm, "Speech_VP")


So this, I believe, conjoins the slices that were separated in the previous plot by the genre variable.
Again, per the model summary, the probability of the N value for the Speech_VP variable is higher than the CH value, so it's higher on the Y axis, but the log odds value of that coefficient is 2.4675, and that does not appear to line up with the blue line of the of the slice representing the N value on the plot. Maybe it lines up with the row of observed values just above it.
But if the the log odds of selecting N over CH is 2.4675, that means the log odds of selecting CH over N is -2.4675 (I changed the reference levels for the Speech_VP variable just to make sure). And -2 doesn't even appear on the plot.
So I don't know how to interpret the ticks on the Y-axis. Anybody know?
The source I was reading doesn't explain, and it looks like visreg rarely if ever gets used for situations like this (where all variables are factors).

The variable on the y-axis appears to be the fitted value of the model.  But I don't think these parallel box plots make much sense here.  That fitted value only takes on few values, so, even if taking the mean or median of them makes sense (which I am not sure of) the box doesn't add much. Can you tell us what exactly you want to plot?

I don't think they're supposed to be box plots, I think the blue lines are the fitted values, the dots are the observed values, and the grey a representation the residuals. See: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/visreg/vignettes/quick-start.html

I remember looking into this source code some time ago; the lines are 100% certainly fitted log-odds. In your first plot they match up perfectly to reference or intercept (PEN/CH = -4.65), Speech_VPN (-4.65 + 2.47 ~ -2.18), GenreTN (-4.65 + 4.06 ~ -0.59), and Speech_VPN/genreTN (-4.65 + 2.47 + 4.06 ~ 1.88). Recall that the predicted probability is the sum of all applicable parameters. I believe the individual points are the observation-level probabilities with some kind of deviance residual added, I couldn't make much sense of those either.
